# Implemention Reddit's Hotness algorithm in web startup

Tags: php, algorithm

I am working on a startup that uses Reddit's algorithm to determine the "Hotness" of posts. I am outlining the basic algorithm in PHP

```
protected function _score($score, $time){
    $start = 1406618304;    //29-Jul-14
    $hop = 45000
    if($score > 0)
        $sign = 1;
    else if($score < 0)
        $sign = -1;
    else
        $sign = 0;

    $order = log( max( abs( $score ), 1));
    $seconds = $time - $start;
    return  round ( $sign * $order +  ( $seconds / $hop ), 7 );
}
```

The variable `$hop` is the most important thing about this question. It is a scale factor that brings the **score** and the age into balance. There are **86,400** seconds in a day, so `$seconds` gets larger by this amount each day.

In the Reddit's algorithm, value of $hop is **45,000**. Dividing `$seconds` by `$hop`(45,000) gives **1.92** which means that one day's relative newness is worth is **83** (10 ^ 1.92) votes (log to the base 10 of 73 = 1.86), and two days' relative newness are worth roughly **6,918** votes. And the number shoots up exponentially.

**83** for one day and **6,918** for two days is good enough for a website like Reddit that has millions of visitors per day. But for a website, in it's early days having only a few hundred page-views per day, those numbers are impossible to nail.

Say there are are 5 posts,

`<post, age, score>`

`<P1, 1 hour,0>`

`<P2, 2 hour,-5>`

`<P3, 2 hour,3>`

`<P4, 3 hour,60>`

`<P5, 4 hour,35>`

The sorted output will be [P1, P3, P2, P4, P5] which is not ideal.

The solution is to tweak the `$hop` value and set it to a higher number so that number of votes get a bigger impact on the resulting score than age.

I am trying to keep an open mind about scalability. So what if the website scales up drastically? Will I need to tweak the `$hop` value again(by lowering it)? If so shouldn't it be distorting the overall ranking?

Comment: Why not calculate a new value for `$hop` periodically, automatically by scaling it according to traffic over the period?

Comment: @JonathanM , that's what I had in my mind but not sure if it wouldn't distort the overall ranking. What do you think?

Comment: You could model the results in a simple spreadsheet and see how it works with different amounts of traffic.